# Get images to line up underneath each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My images are showing up diagonally a little to the left with every row. How can I align the images underneath each other.

Here is the link to my codepen.
https://codepen.io/centem/pen/NgKEmG

Here is my code. I'm using bootstrap.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Username<span class="pull-right">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right">
      <img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li>
            <li>Username<span class="pull-right">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>
            <li>Username<span class="pull-right">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>
            <li>Username<span class="pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>
            <li>Username<span class="pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>
            <li>Username<span class="pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>
            <li>Username<span class="pull-right"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/firefox/firefox_PNG16.png"></span><span class="pull-right"><img src="https://ma.ttias.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/internet-explorer-logo.png"></span></li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: please add below css to your li, 
li {
    margin: 4px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
or
li {
    margin: 4px;
    clear: both;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are bigger than the `li`, and because the images are floating, their height is not properly calculated. You need to `clear: both;` your li.

Just add this :

```
li {
   clear: both;
}
```